# ASP Flash Variables Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, asp-classic

I have .asp data coming into flash through a URLRequest like this:

http://www.thewebsite.com/aspTest.asp?courseNum=123 where courseNum will vary.

This causes an issue with my flash piece because the courseNum var is changing, but still need it to dynamically load the right courseNum. How could I set this up within flash to recgonize what courseNum I need?

Inital though would be to create an input field in flash and have the user enter in the courseNum and submit it which would append the URL and load the data, but Im trying to limit user input to a minium. Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you want to supply the courseNum then? Do you know upon the page load what course it is?

Comment: Yes, once they enter all information on a form a url will be generated like the one shown above. My vision is when they enter that url into their browser a flash object will appear gathering the data via the courseNum. However when I embed a flash object into my asp data page the connections don't work. It will only work if they are seperate i.e. flash in one page and asp data on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...In that case you can pass it using [Flashvars](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html). I also strongly suggest you using SWFObject to embed your swf file - it's a very easy thing to do.

Comment: That will do it! Thank you I was using another method of bringing in the data outside of FlashVars that was causing some fighting between flash and asp. This works perfectly for what I need. Again thank you for your help